# Can we host a gaming convention?

Tags: discussion, top-7, site-promotion

The powers-that-be are looking for fun community events that can drive site promotion. I suggest we host a gaming convention.

In the spirit of "agile development" from the software world, we can start with the smallest possible thing that can be run, and grow organically according to what people need and want to see at the con.

If we put something together that's even remotely in my area (US east coast) I am willing to GM a couple of Shadowrun games.

To get the ball rolling, we need the following:

- A location
- A list of people who are going to show up
- An idea of what they're interested in doing

(Really, any community get-together can be boiled down to these items. I'm suggesting we start with a weekend of RPG gaming.)

Think about it, we do this kind of thing all the time, in our own individual groups. We just need to get organized. =)

Comment: Related: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/205/doing-fun-things

Answer (score 4):

Apologies for re-opening an old question, but I just noticed this, and have experience in this area.

I participated in an online convention (RyvenCon, http://ryvencon.omnivangelist.net) last July, which went very well. GMs submitted games to the con organizer, who added each game to a public calendar along with a blank list of participants. Anyone who wanted to join a game edited the calendar entry, adding their Skype username to the participant list until the list was full.

Games were typically run over Skype, though of course these days one could use Google+ Hangouts.

Answer (score 3):

Well, dibs on running a lot of 4e. ;)

Comment: I so want to play in one of your games.

Answer (score 1):

Given the web-nature of (rpg.)SE.

I suggest this be a 'virtual' Con.

Comment: Being in UK, I vote for the virtual one so I can participate.

Comment: Teleconference-convention?

Comment: so that would be TeleCon?

Comment: Google+ is very popular for this right now, note ConstantCon (http://constantcon.blogspot.com/) - in fact, maybe us pitching in on that and sponsoring a bunch of games would work well.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a cool idea. I want to do something similar on a local level, and even had a question about that. Hmm.

Comment: I don't think we've talked at all about whether or not con-running is on-topic, but it seems to me like it should be if it's tied into the roleplaying aspect. Negotiating with hotels is probably off-topic, finding GMs is on-topic? But this is just my opinion, be ready for disagreement. ;)

Comment: @Bryant - That is an interesting point which deserves its own meta question, methinks.

Comment: Methinks so too.